# How can i make a Unity App run in the new Xcode?

Tags: crash, xcode4.2, unity-game-engine

Hi i am having a problem with the new Xcode 4.2. I am working with Unity and everytime i try to run my apps on a  device it give me a message like that:

```
Nov 18 11:34:57 unknown multiplayertester[3670] <Warning>: -> registered mono modules 0xcbafb8
Nov 18 11:34:58 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[3670] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
Nov 18 11:34:58 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[3670] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/D691EFA3-1EC8-4F8A-A4FB-90329945C4B4 [69] (sandbox)
Nov 18 11:34:58 unknown UIKitApplication:com.XXXXXXXXX.multiplayertester[0x1d92][3670] <Notice>: -> applicationDidFinishLaunching()
Nov 18 11:34:58 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.XXXXXXX.multiplayertester[0x1d92]) Exited with code: 1
Nov 18 11:34:58 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: Application 'realtest' exited abnormally with exit status 1
```

I have been searching everywhere and nobody could answer me. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use Unity 3.4.2 if your device is iPhone or use Unity 3.4.1 with iPad.
2. "Exited with code: 1" means you that should reset Xcode or your Mac.
3. Multiple Xcode 4.2 compilation errors.

At the moment for Xcode 4.0 and later you need manually select proper build target (scheme) and proper target device. That's described on manual page:  http://unity3d.com/support/documenta...roubleShooting